# Chartboost interstitial sometimes crashes when dismissed

Tags: android, chartboost

I'm using the newest Chartboost sdk version (6.5.0). When interstitial closes, sometimes it crashes with the following stacktrace.

```
V/WindowManager( 2344): Window{42dcdee0 u0 Keyguard}mOrientationRequetedFromKeyguard=false
D/WindowManager( 2344): computeScreenConfigurationLocked() set config.orientation=2 dw=1280 dh=720 Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.updateOrientationFromAppTokensLocked:5171 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.updateOrientationFromAppTokens:5142 com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.setRequestedOrientation:3481 
D/PowerManagerService( 2344): setKeyboardVisibility: false
V/WindowManager( 2344): Window{42dcdee0 u0 Keyguard}mOrientationRequetedFromKeyguard=false
E/webview ( 8676): java.lang.Throwable: Error: WebView.destroy() called while still attached!
E/webview ( 8676):  at android.webkit.WebViewClassic.destroy(WebViewClassic.java:4158)
E/webview ( 8676):  at android.webkit.WebView.destroy(WebView.java:707)
E/webview ( 8676):  at com.chartboost.sdk.impl.bi$c.b(SourceFile:116)
E/webview ( 8676):  at com.chartboost.sdk.h.f(SourceFile:318)
E/webview ( 8676):  at com.chartboost.sdk.Model.a.j(SourceFile:375)
E/webview ( 8676):  at com.chartboost.sdk.Model.a.i(SourceFile:351)
E/webview ( 8676):  at com.chartboost.sdk.g.d(SourceFile:232)
E/webview ( 8676):  at com.chartboost.sdk.g$2$1$1.run(SourceFile:150)
E/webview ( 8676):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
E/webview ( 8676):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
E/webview ( 8676):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
E/webview ( 8676):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
E/webview ( 8676):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/webview ( 8676):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
E/webview ( 8676):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
E/webview ( 8676):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
E/webview ( 8676):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
D/webviewglue( 8676): nativeDestroy view: 0x5a74aab8
I/WindowManager( 2344): Screenshot Window{43daca38 u0 com.example.myapp/com.chartboost.sdk.CBImpressionActivity} was all black! mSurfaceLayer=21015 minLayer=21015 maxLayer=21015
F/libc    ( 8676): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000036 (code=1), thread 8676 (id.myapp)
I/DEBUG   ( 2255): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000036
```

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Hi this Ed from Chartboost... Can you email support@chartboost.com with your app id? We want to to look in to this.

Comment: This crash has been fixed with the latest version of the Chartboost SDK. It has been a known issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check your AndroidManifest.xml, Have you added this.  `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"`

It's look like this :

```
<activity android:name="com.chartboost.sdk.CBImpressionActivity"
          android:excludeFromRecents="true"
          android:hardwareAccelerated="true"            
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"   
          android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
```